# Creating a command button in VBA and changing it's name & caption?

Tags: vba, excel, shapes, commandbutton

I have seen many different pages on creating shapes and buttons in VBA macros but none of them worked and I'm getting extremely frustrated.

I tried to use:

```
 Dim sortBtn As Object
    Set sortBtn = Worksheets("Main").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
      Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=200, Top:=100, Width:= 100, Height:=35)
    sortBtn.Name = "Test"     'So far this works
    Worksheets("Main").Shapes(Test).DrawingObject.Object.Caption = "Test2"
    'The above line doesn't work
```

Please do not redirect me to another question, I have read over a dozen on this site and none have helped me further than this point. With this I would also like to choose where the button is placed. I've also tried the shape method:

```
Dim sortBtn As Shape
Set sortBtn = Worksheets("Main").Shapes.AppShape(CommandButton1)
```

I've also tried:

```
With sortBtn.OLEFormat.Object
    .Object.Caption = "Test"
    .Name = "Test"
End With
```

The above also doesn't work with either declaring used above.

Please save me from troubleshooting!

Comment: 1 too many `objects` this works `.oleformat.object.caption="test"`

Comment: I took out the second object and it said Object doesn't support this property or method (wouldn't even give me a location of the error).

Comment: `activesheet.shapes("button 1").oleformat.object.caption` works fine for me.  I don't think this is right `Set sortBtn = Worksheets("Main").Shapes.AppShape(CommandButton1)`

Comment: Is that after declaring it at "Dim sortBtn As Shape"?

Comment: I would look at declaration of `sortBtn` and as you are setting this, you can say `sortBtn.oleformat.object.caption`

Comment: Worksheets("Main").Shapes(Test).DrawingObject.Object.Caption = "Test2"  Test is missed  double qoute. It would to be  Worksheets("Main").Shapes("Test").DrawingObject.Object.Caption = "Test2"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a little too late for this answer but I archive an expected result with the following code:

```
Call Add_Command_Button(Range("R39:S40"), "Next01_Button", "Next")

Sub Add_Command_Button(rngUbicacionControl As Range, sCommandButtonName As String, sCommandButtonCaption As String)
    Dim objCommandButton As Object
    Set objCommandButton = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
        Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
        left:=rngUbicacionControl.left, _
        top:=rngUbicacionControl.top, _
        width:=rngUbicacionControl.width, _
        height:=rngUbicacionControl.height)
    objCommandButton.Name = sCommandButtonName
    objCommandButton.Object.Caption = sCommandButtonCaption
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer @jmejias it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the integrated Macro Recorder, it seems like you can probably look through another way around this.

Here is the complete macro

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(111.75, 60.75, 258, 75.75).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "WhatEverMacroYouNeedtoRunWhenYouClickOnThisButton"
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Test 2"
    With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=13).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

If you look at this code, you will see that it's not really the same type of object. Yours was `OLEobject`, this one is `Button`. Yet, I struggle to find documentation on this object... Therefore, I can't really say what is going to work or not, if this class of object is sufficient or not for your application.

So, if we take this and apply it to your code, we get:

```
Public Sub InsertButton()

    Dim sortBtn As Object
    Set sortBtn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Buttons.Add(Left:=200, _
        Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=35)

    sortBtn.Name = "Test"
    sortBtn.Caption = "Test 2"  '<---This one works.
    sortBtn.Characters.Text = sortBtn.Characters.Text & vbCrLf & "Test 3" <-- This one works too!

End Sub
```

[image: This is the final result]